# SonarQube C# plugin with StyleCop report generated externally

Tags: sonarqube, fxcop

I'm using SonarQube 4.0 with C# plugin v3.1 and FxCop 10. I've seen examples of sonar.properties files that include:

```
sonar.fxcop.mode=reuseReport
```

This would be ideal for me, because the build assemblies are generated on another machine, and reusing the report would enable me to manipulate the file paths in the report to make them match those in the workspace on the Sonar analysis machine (rather than allowing Sonar to run FxCop itself).

However, I can only find references to such a parameter in the outdated Sonar documentation here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/FxCop%2C+Gendarme+and+StyleCop.

I can't see a reference to this parameter from browsing the source of the plugin, but the structure of the plugins has changed so much that I can't find the old source code so I don't know if I'm looking in the right place.

Does anyone know if this parameter still exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updated documentation of the StyleCop plugin is available at: http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=239371014

This page does not mention such a parameter, so I'm pretty sure that it is no more available in the latest versions of the plugin.

Comment: Oops... should have found that myself :-$. Thanks.